# Bootstrap carousel Slider active class and next/prev button not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, umbraco7

I'm using cshtml from Umbraco. I want to create slider on homepage. The image appear on page but "active" item not working. (THIS SOLVED)

**Another problem is I want to add different caption for each slide.** How to add that?

```html
@{   
   var images = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("backgroundSlider").ToList();
}

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  @for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
  {
   <div class="@(i < 1 ? " active":"") item" data-slide-number="@i">
    <img src='@images[i].Url'>
   </div> 
  }
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be your `.carousel-item` class, which was specified as `.item` instead. These have to be the same as they are specified [in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) for everything to work as expected.

```
@{   
   var images = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("backgroundSlider").ToList();
}

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="@(i < 1 ? " active":"") carousel-item" data-slide-number="@i">
                <img src='@images[i].Url' class="d-block w-100">
            </div>  
        }
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

For captioning, this is a suitable Bootstrap docs example that would help you:

```
@{   
var images = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("backgroundSlider").ToList();
}

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="@(i < 1 ? " active":"") carousel-item" data-slide-number="@i">
                <img src='@images[i].Url' class="d-block w-100">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>@images[i].Title</h5>
                <p>@images[i].Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        }
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

In the example above I'm assuming your image title is in your `Title` property and caption is in `Description`. Feel free to amend these as needed.

Comment: Sorry. How to add different caption for different slide number?

Comment: Have added an answer for that as well @Shn. Good luck!